# Filtering more than one record in database table throws up syntax error/access violation

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, sybase-asa, tcxgrid

Using Delphi XE2.

I have a database software package which displays records from a table onto a cxgrid. I have implemented a filter button with at a click of it allows users to search for results using specific records. At the moment it only works when 1 of the records is selected, it doesn't like it when more than one of the filter records is selected, it displays the following error....'syntax error or access violation: near 'and' in...[and]'. The following code is what I'm doing at point of clicking the filter button.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
begin
  with dmData.aQry do
begin
  Close;
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Text:= ('select * from DBA.RECORDS');
  if dbluCaseCategory.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('where category_type like :category_type');
  if dbluSubCategory.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and sub_cat_type like :sub_cat_type');
  if dbluCustomer.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and customer_name like :customer_name');
  if dbluUsername.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and created_by_user like :created_by_user');
  if cxStartDateEdit.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and logged_dt like :logged_dt');

  if dbluCaseCategory.Text <> '' then ParamByName('category_type').Value := dbluCaseCategory.Text +'%';
  if dbluSubCategory.Text <> '' then ParamByName('sub_cat_type').Value := dbluSubCategory.Text +'%';
  if dbluCustomer.Text <> '' then ParamByName('customer_name').Value := dbluCustomer.Text +'%';
  if dbluUsername.Text <> '' then ParamByName('created_by_user').Value := dbluUsername.Text +'%';
  if cxStartDateEdit.Text <> '' then ParamByName('logged_dt').Value := cxStartDateEdit.Text +'%';
  Open;
end;
  Close;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work if you include the first filter (dbluCaseCategory.Text)  because you add the `where` sentence only on that part. So if you don't pass any value to the  `dbluCaseCategory` the final SQL sentence will not be valid. In order to fix that just add a `Where 1=1` in the first sentence. like so.

```
  with dmData.aQry do
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('select * from DBA.RECORDS Where 1=1');
    if dbluCaseCategory.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and category_type like :category_type');
    if dbluSubCategory.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and sub_cat_type like :sub_cat_type');
    if dbluCustomer.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and customer_name like :customer_name');
    if dbluUsername.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and created_by_user like :created_by_user');
    if cxStartDateEdit.Text <> '' then SQL.Add('and logged_dt like :logged_dt');

    if dbluCaseCategory.Text <> '' then ParamByName('category_type').Value := dbluCaseCategory.Text +'%';
    if dbluSubCategory.Text <> '' then ParamByName('sub_cat_type').Value := dbluSubCategory.Text +'%';
    if dbluCustomer.Text <> '' then ParamByName('customer_name').Value := dbluCustomer.Text +'%';
    if dbluUsername.Text <> '' then ParamByName('created_by_user').Value := dbluUsername.Text +'%';
    if cxStartDateEdit.Text <> '' then ParamByName('logged_dt').Value := cxStartDateEdit.Text +'%';
    Open;
```